# Execute function/event on the view before other bindings are applied

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to execute "data-bind" function or "data-bind" event on the **View** before any other bindings will be applied?

I need this behaviour so that I can initialize some part on my viewmodel which is going to be available only from the **View**.

```
// this should be called first
<script type="text/javascript" data-bind="event: { load: initialize('data') }"><script>

// this should be called after
<div data-bind="text: initializedValue">
```

Comment: you are missing a colon in data-bind="event: ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could first bind your script element separately and then bind the rest of your view inside the initialize function ([in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaakkytt/UjSbG/))..

html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="vm1" data-bind="event: { load: initialize('data') }"></script>
<div id="vm2">
    <div data-bind="text: initializedValue">1</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    self=this;
    self.initialize = function(data){
        self.initializedValue=ko.observable('2');
        ko.applyBindings(mvm,document.getElementById('vm2'));
    }
}
var mvm=new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(mvm,document.getElementById('vm1'));
```